# How to add an overall count as a record to a table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have two tables:

**Table1(SOURCE TABLE):
This table keeps track of all the data that is being imported.**

```
  date     | type   | volume | words | words_per | none | none_per
07-APR-21    cats    , 10     , 5     ,  50        , 5    ,50
07-APR-21    dogs     , 10     , 5     ,  50        , 5    ,50
07-APR-21    primates , 10     , 5     ,  50        , 5    ,50
07-APR-21    seafish  , 10     , 5     ,  50        , 5    ,50
06-APR-21    cats    , 10     , 5     ,  50        , 5    ,50
06-APR-21    dogs     , 10     , 5     ,  50        , 5    ,50
06-APR-21    primates , 10     , 5     ,  50        , 5    ,50
06-APR-21    seafish  , 10     , 5     ,  50        , 5    ,50
```

**This is the view I am trying to create that sums up the values for each month and also includes the overall sum of each field(excluding the percentage fields)**

```
  | type   | volume | words | words_per | none | none_per
   cats      , 20     , 10    ,  50%        , 10    ,50%
   dogs      , 20     , 10    ,  50%        , 10    ,50%
  primates    , 20     , 10    ,  50%        , 10    ,50%
  seafish    , 20     , 10    ,  50%        , 10    ,50%
  overall   , 80     , 40    ,   -        ,   40     ,-
```

**I am having issues inserting the overall record to the table that sums up all the values in each field. This is my code so far:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_table1 AS
SELECT type, 
       SUM(NVL(volume,0)) AS volume, 
       SUM(NVL(words,0)) AS words, 
       AVG(NVL(words_per,0))||'%' AS words_per, 
       SUM(NVL(none,0)) AS none, 
       AVG(NVL(none_per,0))||'%' AS none_per
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY type
```

I was thinking maybe a join and insert but I tried that but to no avail. I am new to OracleSQL so any ideas or suggestions would help.

Comment: `group by rollup(type)`. In the `select` clause, you may also want to write `nvl(type, 'overall') as type` to get the `overall` string in the last row in the first column.

Comment: desired output is the view above. I am using table1 to create the view(second table above)

Comment: Mathguy what you said works however is there a way to avoid calculating the fields with percentages (there are two)

Comment: There is, but then you need to read about the `grouping_id` expressions (when you read about `group by rollup` anyway). Read, for example, here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets If you want a query against your exact sample, you will have to post the sample as usable SQL statements (either CREATE TABLE and INSERT, or as a WITH clause; you can search for examples on this site).

Comment: Note that your average computation is probably wrong anyway, even for the types. I assume words_per is the ratio words / volume. If so, and if the "aggregate" average is supposed to be total words / total volume for each type, then that is **not** equal to the average of the individual ratios (words_per) for the type, unless the volumes are all equal within the type - which in general they probably aren't. You should compute the aggregate ratio directly from the totals in the other two columns. For an example: vol 10, words 5, words_per 50%; volume 40, words 10, words_per 25%. (continued)

Comment: Total volume 10 + 40 = 50, total words 5 + 10 = 15. words_per for the totals should be 15/50 or 30%; but the average of 50% and 25% is 37.5%, not 30%. And this is for the total for just one "type". This is basic math, not some PhD level kind of thing.

Comment: Since you're saying you're new to SQL I'd like to comment on your question. A view is just a query over the data and is perfect for adding the columns. The "overall record" doesn't really make sense to be included in a view. Usually that is calculated by the client accessing your data through a query. That "overall record" only makes sense if the client selects all rows, if a where clause is added that overall record will show wrong data...